# Differences between drawing: eg. Graphics.drawRect or Rectangle.draw

Tags: java, design-patterns, graphics, 2d

I am making a basic Java graphics library using OpenGL, and I was thinking about something. My library will be capable of drawing basic shapes, but as far as I am aware, there are two different ways I could do this.

The first way would be similar to how Java draws graphics. There would just be one Graphics class with methods for drawing all different shapes.

So it would look like

```
Graphics g;
g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 20);
```

The second way I thought of doing it would be to have a class for every shape (inside a Graphics package).

So it would look something like this:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 20);
```

Then you would draw it like this:

```
rect.draw(0, 0);
```

That way you could also have methods like

```
rect.setSize(50, 50);
rect.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

To change the properties of the rectangle before it is actually drawn.

What are the advantages of both?

Comment: That, comes down entrily to you and what you want to achieve. I like the idea of base shapes as it provides the ability to generate a lot of additional, related code

Comment: Removed last question as it would lead to opinionated answers. Asking about differences / advantages is usually OK, which one is "best" is not as that's subjective.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a composite design pattern. See [Composite Pattern - Shapes Example - Java Sourcecode](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern-shapes-example-java-sourcecode.html) for more information.

> In graphics editors a shape can be basic or complex. An example of a simple shape is a line, where a complex shape is a rectangle which is made of four line objects. Since shapes have many operations in common such as rendering the shape to screen, and since shapes follow a part-whole hierarchy, **composite pattern can be used to enable the program to deal with all shapes uniformly**.